# In material-react-table how do I set the initial rows per page?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-react-table

I'm not able to set the initial rows per page in material-react-table.

The [documentation](https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination) shows how to set rowsPerPage options, but the initial rows per page remains at 10 even when I remove 10 as an option:

```
<MaterialReactTable
  columns={columns}
  data={data}
  muiTablePaginationProps={{
    rowsPerPageOptions: [20, 50],
    showFirstButton: false,
    showLastButton: false,
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok figured it out, it's explained in the docs: https://www.material-react-table.com/docs/guides/pagination

You need to add `initialState` to `<MaterialReactTable />`. The `pageSize` value sets the default initial rows per page.

```
<MaterialReactTable
  ...
  initialState={{
    pagination: {
      pageIndex: 0,
      pageSize: 20,
    },
  }}
/>
```

*Side note: to those in charge of the documentation, would save everyone time putting this together with `rowsPerPageOptions`, because anybody updating rows per page options is naturally going to want to update the initial rows per page state.*

Comment: https://github.com/KevinVandy/material-react-table/edit/main/apps/material-react-table-docs/pages/docs/guides/pagination.mdx

You can use this link to suggest the improvement to the docs directly!